# Python function to approximate mathematical value of e

Tags: python, math

I am writing a function to approximate the mathematical value of e.

We are told to use the `factorial` function and the `inverse` function above. It is also suggested to use `map`.

I have this so far, but it gives me an error saying: `ValueError: factorial() only accepts integral values`.

```
def inverse(n):
    """Returns the inverse of n"""
    return 1 / n

def e(n):
    """Approximates the mathematical value e"""
    lst = range(1, n+1)
    lst2 = map(inverse, lst)
    lst3 = map(math.factorial, lst2)
    return sum(lst3)
```

Could someone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Hint: does inverting an integer return an integer?

Comment: Are you using python 2 or 3. I guess 3 because `1 / 2` would produce a `float` in 3 and an integer in 2.

Comment: @HughBothwell with Py2 integer division - always :)

Comment: Are you sure you're not meant to do `factorial` first, then `inverse`?

Comment: @PeterWood python 3. I tried doing `1 // n`, but now my answers are rounding to the nearest integer and I need them to be a float

Comment: @PeterWood I just tried that, but the answers are 1 below what they should be. For example, `e(2) = 2.6666666` but I am getting `e(2) = 1.6666666`

Comment: You should go from zero: `range(0, n+1)`, as `0! == 1`. Obviously you couldn't do inverse on `0` but you can on `0!`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now working for me. I needed to change the range from `(1, n+1)` to `(0, n+1)` and reverse the order of doing the `factorial` first and then doing the `inverse`.

```
def inverse(n):
    """Returns the inverse of n"""
    return 1 / n


def e(n):
    """Approximates the mathematical value e"""
    lst = map(math.factorial, range(0, n+1))
    return sum(map(inverse, lst))
```

Answer (score 1):

*e* can be defined by Σ(1/k!), where k = 0 .. ∞.

So, for each k,

1. compute k!
2. invert
3. add to total

It looks like you're doing the inversion before the factorial instead of after, and starting from 1 instead of 0.

Note that this is not the most efficient way of doing this computation, as the factorial is unnecessarily being computed from scratch for each k.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone else pointed out:

- You are missing the first term in the series which is 1.
- In python, the division gives you an integer value if both numbers are integers. i.e. `1/2 == 0`.

You need something like this:

```
def inverse(n):
    """Returns the inverse of n"""
    # Using 1 as a float makes the division return a float value.
    return 1. / n

def e(n):
    """Approximates the mathematical value e"""
    lst = range(1, n+1) # k=1...n
    lst2 = map(math.factorial, lst)
    return 1 + sum(map(inverse, lst2))
```

You can compare your approximation against `math.exp`:

```
>>> abs(math.exp(1) - e(20)) < 1e-10
True
```

Answer (score 0):

I has some fun with that question, using generators and decorators. First, you can create a generator to `yield` consecutively more precise values of `e`:

```
def compute_e():
    currentFactorial = 1
    currentSum = 1
    for i in itertools.count(start=1):
        currentFactorial *= i
        currentSum += 1/currentFactorial
        yield currentSum
```

And, after that, I create a decorator to find a fixed point (with a maximum number of iterations, and wanted precision) :

```
def getFixedPoint(gen, maxiter=10000, precision=0):
    def mywrap(*args, **kwargs):
        instanceGen = gen(*args, **kwargs)
        prevValue = next(instanceGen)
        for n, value in enumerate(instanceGen):
            if (value - prevValue < precision) or (n > maxiter):
                return value
            else:
                prevValue = value
    return mywrap
```

which gives me stuff like this:

```
In [83]: getFixedPoint(compute_e)()
Out[83]: 2.7182818284590455

In [84]: getFixedPoint(compute_e, maxiter=5)()
Out[84]: 2.71827876984127

In [85]: getFixedPoint(compute_e, precision = 0.001)()
Out[85]: 2.7182539682539684
```

Of cours, now I can change my way of computing each successive value of `e`, for example by using `from decimal import Decimal`:

```
@getFixedPoint
def compute_e():
    currentFactorial = Decimal(1)
    currentSum = Decimal(1)
    for i in itertools.count(start=1):
        currentFactorial *= i
        currentSum += 1/currentFactorial
        yield currentSum

compute_e()
Out[95]: Decimal('2.718281828459045235360287474')
```